# Magento2 : How to swap the footer links/contents?

Tags: magento2, footer, theme-overriding

[image]

How can I swap these two elements present in the footer section in the **Magento 2** I installed ?

Comment: Checkout into your back-end you must have some blocks created there & make the required changes from there

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 you can use the `move` to swap the position of any element as :

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" 
 after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use Move element to swap that**

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="-"/>
```

Comment: I tried this block of codes and failed : <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="-"/>  <move element="footer_links" destination="footer" after="-"/>

Comment: you can try this                                                                                            
 <move element="cms_footer_links_container" destination="form.subscribe" before="-"/>             
 <move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer_links" before="-"/>